# How to convert multidimensional array into json object

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i have an issue in array to json conversion, I have an array and i want to convert this array into json objects, desired output given below so any one please help me.

Php array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [application_id] => 132
            [application_status] => SUBMITTED
            [reference_number] => 
            [salutation] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [mother_name] => 


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [application_id] => 148
            [application_status] => SUBMITTED
            [reference_number] => 
            [salutation] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [mother_name] => 


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [application_id] => 154
            [application_status] => SUBMITTED
            [reference_number] => 
            [salutation] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [mother_name] => 


        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [application_id] => 182
            [application_status] => SUBMITTED
            [reference_number] => 
            [salutation] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [mother_name] => 


        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [application_id] => 186
            [application_status] => SUBMITTED
            [reference_number] => 
            [salutation] => 
            [first_name] => 
            [middle_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [mother_name] => 



        )

)
```

Convert above array to json object like this:

```
[
        {
            "application_id": "1",
            "application_status": "0",
            "reference_number": "/index",
            "salutation": "index",
            "first_name": "Index",
            "middle_name": "Home",
            "last_name": "1",

        },
        {
            "application_id": "1",
            "application_status": "0",
            "reference_number": "/index",
            "salutation": "index",
            "first_name": "Index",
            "middle_name": "Home",
            "last_name": "1",

        },
        {
            "application_id": "1",
            "application_status": "0",
            "reference_number": "/index",
            "salutation": "index",
            "first_name": "Index",
            "middle_name": "Home",
            "last_name": "1",

        },
        {
            "application_id": "1",
            "application_status": "0",
            "reference_number": "/index",
            "salutation": "index",
            "first_name": "Index",
            "middle_name": "Home",
            "last_name": "1",

        },
        {
            "application_id": "1",
            "application_status": "0",
            "reference_number": "/index",
            "salutation": "index",
            "first_name": "Index",
            "middle_name": "Home",
            "last_name": "1",

        },

]
```

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) ?

Comment: Do you really want to have some duplicates in a JSON object which came from no-where!, or it's just a typo!!

Comment: No No its just a typo error, every key have different values. @someOne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your desired output suggests it is an array of objects. Just loop over them and encode each subarray to json string, and decode it again to obtain an object:

```
foreach($array as $k =>$a){
    $array[$k] = json_decode(json_encode($a));
}
```

If however you mean you want an array of json strings, omit the `json_decode`:

```
foreach($array as $k =>$a){
    $array[$k] = json_encode($a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for this problem? This will convert the passed argument to a JSON object.

Comment: No json_encode give data like this:
{
  "0": {
    "application_id": "132",
    "application_status": "SUBMITTED",
    "reference_number": null,
    "salutation": null,
}
"1":{
     "application_id": "134",
    "application_status": "SUBMITTED",
    "reference_number": null,
    "salutation": null,
}

Answer (score -1):

Just use json_encode()

```
<?php    
$array = Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "application_id" => "132",
            "application_status" => "SUBMITTED",
            "reference_number" => "",
            "salutation" => "",
            "first_name" => "",
            "middle_name" => "",
            "last_name" => "",
            "mother_name" => ""    
        ),    
    "1" => Array
        (
            "application_id" => "148",
            "application_status" => "SUBMITTED",
            "reference_number" => "",
            "salutation" => "",
            "first_name" => "",
            "middle_name" => "",
            "last_name" => "",
            "mother_name" => ""    
        ),    
    "2" => Array
        (
            "application_id" => "154",
            "application_status" => "SUBMITTED",
            "reference_number" => "",
            "salutation" => "",
            "first_name" => "",
            "middle_name" => "",
            "last_name" => "",
            "mother_name" => ""    
        ),    
    "3" => Array
        (
            "application_id" => "182",
            "application_status" => "SUBMITTED",
            "reference_number" => "",
            "salutation" => "",
            "first_name" => "",
            "middle_name" => "",
            "last_name" => "",
            "mother_name" => ""    
        ),    
    "4" => Array
        (
            "application_id" => "186",
            "application_status" => "SUBMITTED",
            "reference_number" => "",
            "salutation" => "",
            "first_name" => "",
            "middle_name" => "",
            "last_name" => "",
            "mother_name" => ""    
        )    
);


$json = json_encode($array);

print_r($json);

?>
```